# Galois Group of a rational polynomial

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

How could I do to calculate the Galois group of a polynomial with rational coefficients ?

Have you some links or books where I could find an answer ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "calculate"... in general, it's a difficult problem.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Actually I would like to know if there are some technics as in the case of integers coefficients.